# Как изменить цвет системного статусбара

Tags: android

Необходимо программно изменить цвет status bar в Lollipop. Использую следующий код:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.status_bar_color));
    window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Цвет меняется, но с ним меняется и размер окна. В результате, кнопки расположенные внизу уползают за navigation bar. Если убрать флаг `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS`, то цвет не меняется. Как можно поменять цвет статус бара не меняя размер окна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, такой глюк может происходить из-за библиотеки SlidingMenu. Там вручную устанавливаются отступы и на Lollipop не учитывается размер navigation bar. Решение можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/680#issuecomment-66604727).

Answer (score 2):

Написать свой стиль и переопределить в нем colorPrimaryDark
Где надо, этот стиль применять

Подробно все описано тут:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Comment: Унаследовал тему приложения от Theme.Material.Light и переопределил в стилях colorPrimaryDark. Проблема ровно та же самая: цвет нормально меняется, но при этом окно расползается по высоте. Еще и отступы по бокам появились. Как сделать так, чтобы ничего окно не расползалось по высоте?

Comment: В коде уже ничего не меняете, только стилем, верно? Могу узнать на чем тестируете?

Comment: Да, только стилем. Тестирую на разных устройствах, Samsung S4, Nexus 5, эмуляторы - встроенные и Genymotion.

Comment: У меня Nexus 5 c 5.1.1, всегда меняю ститем цвета, ни разу ни сталкивался с подобным как Вы описываете. У меня больше нет идей, смотрите код, где-то там что-то не так.